# What is Flash ClockworkMod Recovery?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is ClockworkMOD Recovery and what is it for?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5113/what-is-clockworkmod-recovery-and-what-is-it-for)

I'm trying to use the Rom Manager to partition my SD card (so I can increase the storage size for my apps, since it natively installs to the first available partition which is known as "internal" and the rest of the sd card is "sd"), however, it asks me to install the ClockworkMod Recovery first. If I choose to install, will this install to the emmc or the sd card? I remember reading somewhere that installing ClockworkMod will void the Nook's warranty.

Answer (score 1):

ClockworkMod Recovery is an custom recovery for Android phones, which is installed on the recovery partition on the internal memory.
AFAIK flashing CWM doesn't void the warranty, but rooting does.

Comment: Flashing voids your warranty.

Comment: While this doesn't answer the text of the question, it answers the title... no reason to downvote it...

Comment: Since you can't flash a recovery without rooting first (AFAIK), this seems… borderline recursive :)

Comment: rooting doesn't necessarily void your warranty. I've un-rooted and returned a device back to the manufacturer (Samsung) for repair and was fixed without complaint or charge

Comment: @Michael No, that just means Samsung couldn't tell you had rooted and thus *didn't realize* you had voided your warranty.  Jemus42, you certainly can flash without root on some devices :)

Answer (score 0):

"Flash" is a verb, meaning to write to flash memory or to any kind of ROM.  The verb is most often used in connection with firmware.

CWM normally it overwrites the default recovery, but I believe it can go on the SD card when dual-booting ROMs, which might be the case for the Nook since I don't believe you overwrite the original firmware.  As you noted, it will void your warranty if installed device-side.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this. I've followed this guide: forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1000957 - I probably won't void the warranty since I'm installing it to the SD, if I choose to install via the rom manager. Right?