# If I can flash a ROM using adb or SP Flash Tool, is CWM (ClockWorkMod) Recovery really needed?

Tags: adb, clockworkmod-recovery

I have a general question about flashing ROMs and recovery. I've flashed stock ROM on my Asus Fonepad before using `adb` & `fastboot` when their last OTA update had issues. Similarly, I've used the SP Flash Tool too to backup and flash ROMs on my MTK6572 based mobile in the past.

However, I've been hearing a lot about CWM recovery. Of what use it really is? Is it just another flashing tool like the others?

**edit**

As explained in comments, I know what CWM Recovery is and is used for. I specifically want to know what extra benefit it offers that others like adb/fastboot and SP_Flash_Tool don't?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is ClockworkMod Recovery and what is it for?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5113/what-is-clockworkmod-recovery-and-what-is-it-for)

Comment: @bmdixon Actually not. I know what CWM Recovery is and is used for. I specifically want to know what extra benefit it offers that others like adb/fastboot and SP_Flash_Tool don't?

Comment: @PrahladYeri In the field of flashing something, one software generally equals another, as long as both are supported on a certain device. So, no, the CWM and TWRP are Recovery tools which are able to flash software, but that's not their main purpose.

Comment: Problem is, someone has to make the ROMs you want in SPFlashTool's format and sign it properly (?) for it to work. It also requires a PC by your side. Since it's restricted to MediaTek devices, people just go the universal route instead.

Answer (score 0):

Rest of tools require a pc to flash but this CWM stays in your mobile and you can flash roms directly just using your own mobile.